# Efficient algorithm for string matching with a very large pattern set

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm able to find all patterns that match a specific string. The pattern set can be very large (more than 100,000) and dynamic (patterns added or removed at anytime). Patterns are not necessarily standard regexp, they can be a subset of regexp or something similar to shell pattern (ie: `file-*.txt`). **A solution for a subset of regex is preferred (as explained below).**

**FYI: I'm not interested by brute force approaches based on a list of RegExp.**

By simple regexp, I mean a regular expression that supports `?`, `*`, `+` , character classes `[a-z]` and possibly the logical operator `|`.

To clarify my need: I wish find all patterns that match the URL:

```
http://site1.com/12345/topic/news/index.html
```

The response should be these patterns based on the pattern set below.

```
http://*.site1.com/*/topic/*
http://*.site1.com/* 
http://*
```

Pattern set:

```
http://*.site1.com/*/topic/*
http://*.site1.com/*/article/*
http://*.site1.com/* 
http://*.site2.com/topic/*
http://*.site2.com/article/*
http://*.site2.com/* 
http://*
```

Comment: Will your pattern set always relate to URLs, or is that just an example?

Comment: I would make a brute force implementation to serve as a reference and measure the effectiveness (and accuracy) of you alternative approaches against that.

Comment: Could you clarify what regex grammar you have in mind?

Comment: By simple regexp, I mean a regular expression that supports ?, *, + , character classes [a-z] and possibly the logical operator |

Comment: Thanks @jsobo for this proposition. Much appreciated!

Comment: If you like the answers you see, you should upvote them.

Comment: Sure I'll do it when my reputation score will be more than 15. I recently opened my stackoverflow account.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach we've used pretty successfully ([implementation here](https://github.com/zeek/paraglob)):

**Adding Patterns:**

For any pattern there exists a set of sub-strings a string must contain in order to have a chance of matching against it. Call these meta words. For example:

```
dog*fish -> [dog, fish]
[lfd]og  -> [og]
dog?     -> [dog]
```

When you add a pattern to the data structure, break it up into meta words and store them in a Aho-Corasick string matching data structure. Maintain an internal data structure to map meta words back to pattern words.

**Running Queries:**

Given an input string, use the Aho-Corasick data structure you've built to get all the meta words contained in that string. Then, using the map you've created, test the patterns that correspond to those meta words.

This works well because while string matching is fairly slow, you can narrow down the number of patterns you actually have to match against very quickly. Our [implementation](https://github.com/zeek/paraglob) can perform about 200,000 queries per second, on a regular laptop, against sets of 150,000+ patterns. See the bench-marking mode in the program to test that.

Answer (score 2):

One approach that comes to mind is to create  tree structures of patterns.

Example: `http://*` would contain all the patterns (listed above).  `http://*.site1.com/*` would contain all the `site1.com` ones. This could significantly reduce the number of patterns that need to be checked.

Additionally you could determine which patters are mutually exclusive to further prune the list you search.

So first take all the patterns and create trees out of them.  Search all roots to determine which branches and nodes need to be analyzed.

Improve the algorithm by determining which branches are mutually exclusive so once you find a hit on a given branch  you would know which branches/nodes do not need to be visited.

To get started you could be lazy and your first pass could be to sort the patterns and do simple does next pattern contain this pattern type logic to determine if "this" is contained in next.  EX: `if( "http://*.site1.com/*".startsWith("http://*") == true )`

You could get more sophisticated in your ability to determine if one pattern does actually contain another but this would get you started.

To get any better at determining the question:

> "Does this pattern contain that pattern?"

I believe you would need to be able to parse the regex... This article looks like a good place to start with to understand how to accomplish that: [Parsing regular expressions with recursive descent](http://matt.might.net/articles/parsing-regex-with-recursive-descent/)

Comment: Should be enough and efficient to match shell patterns but more difficult to apply for a simple regexp. If no solution exists for simple regexp I'll take this approach. I completed my question to clarify the term simple regexp. Thanks

Comment: this is tricky because of cases like this:  ...dont[1234].*  and ...don[et][345] and ...don[et][23456] it is obvoius to a human which is contain within the others however to program that is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

If the set of URLs doesn't change very fast, you really should use a regex engine that compiles down its patterns.  Java provides one of these, but it might not be satisfactory if you want to know *which* pattern matches.

A widely used mechanism for doing this *and* determining which match, are various lexer generators, e.g., FLEX and similar tools.  They accept what amount to a regex for each "lexeme", and build an integrated FSA to recognize any of them which is extremely efficient to execute.

You could invoke Flex when your set changes.  If that's too slow, get an open source version of Flex and integrate into your engine; it internally builds the FSA so you could use it directly.  (Some engineering likely necessary).   But if you really have a high performance matching problem, some work to do it well won't bother you.

If the set of URLs changes faster than FLEX can generate FSAs (odd), you have a real problem. In that case, you might build an online discrimination tree by scanning the "regex" from left to right and integrating the characters/predicates you see into your existing discrimination tree.  Matching then consists of walking down the discrimination tree, performing the various tests; if you arrive at a leaf, you have a match, otherwise not.   This might be just as fast as a FLEX-generated automation if done right, but likely a lot, lot bigger.

Comment: First thank you for this interesting answer. Yes I would like to know patterns that match the url. Finally, a post-processing is performed on candidate patterns to elect the best pattern. So a solution based on a big regex is not possible IMO. I will test a solution based on Flex on JFlex with 100K patterns to check the feasability/performance of this approach. I'll post the result the next week.

Comment: Results are not good... The conversion time of NFA to DFA is just too prohibitive in CPU+Memory if the number of patterns is too large. I tested JFlex to generate a scanner for 10000 patterns and I wait always the result (even with the option --nomin). Same observation when I use a library such as http://www.brics.dk/automaton/

Comment: What's are the performance numbers you see? Curious minds want to know. 0) Who cares about memory? 8Gb RAM is $100.00; 1) I'd check out gnu Flex ("the Fast Lexical Analyzer").  Seen lots more miles and years, likely had some serious performance polishing.  2) You can always run this in background, living with the current lexer until the new version is complete.  3) the alternative, the discrimination net, is likely to have a big memory footprint, too, since it is a *tree* with 100,000 paths and leaves and you lose the expressiveness of regexes.

Comment: Well now my tests are based on FLEX and results are not better unfortunately. 32s to generate lex.yy.c for 800 patterns and FLEX refuses an input file with 900 patterns (error msg: input rules are too complicated (>= 32000 NFA states)). I'm trying to explore a solution based on Ternary Search Tree.

Comment: Looks like FLEX failed to live up to its reputation. How fast does the set of URLs change (how many changes per day?).  Are you willing to send me your (realistic) sample of 100K patterns?  I have a lexer I'd like to try this on. See my bio for contact data.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a preference for the format of patterns? Flex format?

Comment: Flex format is fine.  I can massage them into the format I need likely pretty easily.